# SQL Server bcp: how retrieve xml field with escaped double quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, bcp

I am using [SQL Server bcp utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) to extract data from a table. In particular there is an xml column (type XML, not VARCHAR) which could have nested double quotes in attributes, like the following:

```
<test>
    <tag1 att1="Hello "world""></tag1>
</test>
```

The problem is when I try to extract rows using the bcp command I get not properly formatted xml (nested double quotes are not properly escaped using the [`&quot;`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22/index.htm) character).

I expect something like this, which could be properly parsed:

```
<test>
    <tag1 att1="Hello &quot;world&quot;"></tag1>
</test>
```

But I get this:

```
<test>
    <tag1 att1="Hello "world""></tag1>
</test>
```

which is not valid xml and could not be parsed.
Is there any way I can tell SQL Server that should give me in output valid escaped xml?

Comment: This is something you really should solve at the XML's creation. The given sample is plain wrong... You can use single quotes outside and double quotes inside without any hassel (or the other way round). How would you know, if the quote before *world* is *within*?. Solving this, would need to run through the string character by character and write something like a XML parser yourself...

Comment: After some research it seems this is a bug of the `bcp` utility. XML data is correct inside the database table, but it is not properly escaped when you try to retrieve it using the utility. This does not happen using for example jdbc driver for sql server, in that case the xml data is properly escaped.